# failed health check in ABL AWS with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, health-check

I try to create a VPC with 4 subnets(2 public, 2 private) with 2 ALBs, 2ASG, 2 NATGateways and 4 EC2 instances(2 in public and 2 in private) using cloudformation.
Everything works fine except one of the instance in private subnet always failed to pass the health check with timeout error. I checked quite a few times for the code and could not find out what went wrong. Please help to point out what I have done wrong.
I tried several time, always the instance in privatesubnetB(10.0.4.0) failed the health check
Here is the code.

```
Parameters:
  NumberofAZs:
    Type: Number
    AllowedValues:
      - 1
      - 2
    Default: 2
    Description: How many AZ do you want to utilize
  PrivateSubnet:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False
    Default: True
    Description: Do you want to build private subnet
  NumberofPrivateSubnets:
    Type: Number
    AllowedValues:
      - 1
      - 2
    Default: 1
    Description: How many private subnet do you want to create
  NatGateway:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False
    Default: True
    Description: Do you want to create NAT Gateway for private subnet
  KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
Conditions:
  Build2Public: !Not [!Equals [!Ref NumberofAZs, 1]]
  Build3Public: !Equals [!Ref NumberofAZs, 3]
  BuildPrivateSubnet: !Equals [!Ref PrivateSubnet, True]
  BuildOnePrivateSubnet: !And [!Equals [!Ref PrivateSubnet, True],!Equals [!Ref NumberofPrivateSubnets, 1]]
  BuildTwoPrivateSubnet: !And [!Equals [!Ref PrivateSubnet, True], !Equals [!Ref NumberofPrivateSubnets, 2]]
  BuildNatGateway: !Equals [!Ref NatGateway, True]
Resources:
  myVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/21
      Tags:
        - Key: Name     
          Value: myVPC1
  mySecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: allow8000
      GroupDescription: Allow 80 8000 to client host
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 8000
          ToPort: 8000
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  myOwnACL:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: allow8000
  InboundRule:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref myOwnACL
      RuleNumber: 100
      Protocol: 6
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: 172.16.0.0/24
      PortRange:
        From: 8000
        To: 8000
  OutboundRule:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref myOwnACL
      RuleNumber: 100
      Protocol: -1
      Egress: true
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  PublicSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]   
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Public-A
  PublicSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Condition: Build2Public
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true 
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Public-B
  PrivateSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Condition: BuildPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]   
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Private-A
  PrivateSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Condition: BuildTwoPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.4.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ]    
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Private-B
  mySubnetNetworkAclAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
    Condition: BuildTwoPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetB
      NetworkAclId: !Ref myOwnACL
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    DependsOn: myVPC
  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  NATGateway:
    Condition: BuildNatGateway
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt ElasticIPAddress.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA
      ConnectivityType: public
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub NAT-${AWS::StackName}
  NATGatewayB:
    Condition: BuildNatGateway
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt ElasticIPAddress2.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetB
      ConnectivityType: public
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub NAT-${AWS::StackName}-B
  ElasticIPAddress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Condition: BuildPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      Domain: VPC
  ElasticIPAddress2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Condition: BuildPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      Domain: VPC
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public
  PublicRoute1: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Condition: BuildPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private
  PrivateRoute1: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Condition: BuildNatGateway  
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NATGateway
  PrivateRouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Condition: BuildPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private
  PrivateRoute2: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Condition: BuildNatGateway  
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NATGatewayB
  PublicSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Condition: Build2Public
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetB
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PrivateSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Condition: BuildPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetA
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
  PrivateSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Condition: BuildTwoPrivateSubnet
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetB
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2

  MyEC2LaunchTemplate:   
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: ami-05064bb33b40c33a2
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        Monitoring:
          Enabled: true
        SecurityGroupIds: 
          - !Ref mySecurityGroup
        DisableApiTermination: true
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: terminate
        HibernationOptions:
          Configured: true
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - Ebs:
              VolumeSize: 8
              VolumeType: gp2
              DeleteOnTermination: true
              Encrypted: true    
            DeviceName: /dev/xvda
        UserData:
          Fn::Base64:
            !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -ex
            sudo yum install -y httpd;
            sudo echo "<html><h1>Hello CloudFormation A!!<h1></html>" > /var/www/html/index.html;
            cd /var/www/html;
            sudo chmod 755 index.html;
            sudo service httpd start;
            sudo chkconfig httpd on;
  MyASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      MinSize: '1'
      MaxSize: '3'
      DesiredCapacity: '2'
      TargetGroupARNs:
        - !Ref MyTargetGroup
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref MyEC2LaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt MyEC2LaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetA
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetB

  ####### Target group
  MyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: MyTargets
      TargetType: instance
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 80
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckPort: 80
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2


############# Internal ALB
  myInternalALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Name: testALB
      Scheme: internal
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref mySecurityGroup
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetA
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetB
      Type: application
  myInternalALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
          - Type: forward
            TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref myInternalALB
      Port: '80'
      Protocol: HTTP

  exASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      MinSize: '1'
      MaxSize: '3'
      DesiredCapacity: '2'
      TargetGroupARNs:
        - !Ref MyexTargetGroup
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref MyEC2LaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt MyEC2LaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref PublicSubnetA
        - !Ref PublicSubnetB
#    CreationPolicy:
#      ResourceSignal:
#        Count: 2
#        Timeout: 'PT10M'

  ####### Target group for public subnets
  MyexTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: MyexTargets
      TargetType: instance
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 80
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckPort: 80
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 10


############# External ALB
  myExternalALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Name: testExALB
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref mySecurityGroup
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnetA
        - !Ref PublicSubnetB
      Type: application
  myExternalALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
          - Type: forward
            TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyexTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref myExternalALB
      Port: '80'
      Protocol: HTTP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myOwnACL` is **misconfigured** and only used in `Private-B` subnet. Your website is on port 80, not 8000. Also why do you have

```
CidrBlock: 172.16.0.0/24
```

if your vpc is 10.0.0.0/16?

Just remove your custom ACL, and **use default ACLs**.